# Storing a file name and directory in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been attempting to use a dictionary to store a users chosen file directory and filename. Currently I have been running this code with a tkinter GUI class (its fairly large so I won't paste it here)

```
filenames = StringVar()
filedirects ={}

def openfiledirect(self):
    global filenames
    directretr = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select file",
                                            filetypes=(("fasta files", "*.fasta"), ("all files", "*.*")))

    if directretr not in filedirects:
        filedirects[directretr] = os.path.split(directretr)[1][:13]

    names = ''
    for directory in filedirects[directretr]:
        names = filedirects[directretr]
        print(directory)
        print(names)
    filenames.set(names)
```

I inserted the print's in the directory for loop so that I could see what was being stored in the dictionary, and this is what is printed when an example file (R1.fasta) is selected:

```
R
R1.fasta
1
R1.fasta
.
R1.fasta
f
R1.fasta
a
R1.fasta
s
R1.fasta
t
R1.fasta
a
R1.fasta
```

So it appears it isn't storing the file directory at all, but just the individual characters of the file name, and I am unsure why. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The line: `for directory in filedirects[directretr]:` does indeed iterate over the characters in a filename.

Comment: Oh I see, however why isn't it iterating over the whole file directory rather than just the name? And is there any simplistic way to retrieve the entire string rather than it iterate character by character?

Comment: It sounds like you need something like `os.walk`